# EB OPEN SSL VERSION vs HTTP Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

With `eb open` is it possible to make it open my actual url which is ssl (https) vs the dev version which is http? OR how do I make my environment work with ssl?

Screenshot of env below:
[image]

My site works.. with the ssl at [theslimfatty.com](https://theslimfatty.com) which is being aliased by the Amazon Route 53:

[image]

the-slim-fatty-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com (is http) (`eb open` launches this) and I have a config which changes all http to https which only works proberly with the aliased public-facing theslimfatty.com. I hope this all makes sense.
THANKS.

Not secure since this is not not the actual domain:
[image]

Comment: The problem is the certificate's common name is "theslimfatty.com" and it doesn't match with the DNS name of your EBS domain name. Does this help with your question? 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/